# How do I deal with the error "expected loop"?

Tags: windows, vbscript

My code doesn't work

i am trying show my friends

this is the code it is a message box

```
Dim objShell, strComputer, strInput
Dim strRestart

pass=inputbox( "test time! what is 2+2?" )

if pass="4" then

msgbox=( "you is smart" )

else 

DO

msgbox( "you cant do math now i will self destruct" )


Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 0"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first error you have: Move your Dim strRestart to a newline.

I.E: Instead of

```
Dim objShell, strComputer, strInput Dim strRestart
```

Use:

```
Dim objShell, strComputer, strInput
Dim strRestart
```

Second error is on line 4:

```
msgbox=("you is smart")
```

it should be

```
msgbox("you is smart")
```

Third error is on line 6:

Remove the DO. The DO is part of a DO .. WHILE statement for looping,
and it seems that you only want to have an if/else clause.

All in all:

```
Dim objShell, strComputer, strInput
Dim strRestart

pass=inputbox( "test time! what is 2+2?" )

if pass="4" then
    msgbox( "you is smart" )
else
    msgbox( "you cant do math now i will self destruct" )
    Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 0"
end if
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate this.